# Laravel One-to-Many and One-To-One relationship between the same tables

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have 2 tables:
Tourists,
Tours. (and corresponding models Tourist, Tour).

I have successfully set up many-to-many relationship between them. When I

```
$tour->tourists()->attach($tourist);
```

It creates a new record in a table Tour_Tourists. (tour_id, tourist_id, created_at, updated_at). It shows which tourists go with the particular tour.

Now I need to create another entity: Buyer. The buyer is one of the Tourists who pays for the Tour. Only one of the tourists belonging to the tour can be a Buyer.

I have set up one-to-one relations in both models:

```
<?php
```

namespace App;

class Tour extends Model
{
    public function tourists() {

```
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tourist')
    ->withTimestamps();

}

public function buyer() {

    return $this->hasOne('App\Tourist')
    ->withTimestamps();

}
```

}

(and the same in Tourist model, except i changed 'App\Tourist' to 'App\Tour':

```
public function buyer() {

return $this->hasOne('App\Tour')
->withTimestamps();
```

)

but when I do:

```
$tour->buyer()->($tourist)
```

(where $tour and $tourist contain respective records from database), i get:

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTimestamps()'
```

I have a feeling that I am doing it totally wrong. Can anyone just point out the direction I should move on to?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

withTimestamps() is a method used for belongsToMany only because it updates the created_at/updated_at fields of the pivot table.  hasOne won't have this method.

Comment: Thank you, Devon! But I think that my overall approach is wrong. What would you do in my place?

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you wrote how your database is set up for the buyer.  I'd rewrite a new question focusing on your other problem, but be more clear and concise.  SO is about helping future users as much as current users, so good questions/answers should focus on one clear+concise issue.